# Prove that $A$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I need to prove that the following set is open.
$$A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}, |z-z_0|<r \ \mbox{and}\ |z-z_1|<s\},$$

where $r,s>0$ and $|z-z_0|<r+s$.

My ideia is the following: if $z\in A$, the condition $|z-z_0|<r$ represents an open disk centered at $z_0$ and radius $r$. In the same way, $|z-z_1|<r$ represents an open disk centered at $z_1$ and radius $s$. Choosing $\epsilon=r+s+1$, we have
$$|z-z_0|<r<r+s<r+s+1=\epsilon$$
and
$$|z-z_1|<s<r+s<r+s+1=\epsilon$$
Does this prove that $A$ is open?

Comment: As far as I understand, $A$ is the intersection of two open balls (centered at $z_0$ and $z_1$)... so it is open.

Comment: yes, but I would prefer not to use this fact

Comment: If Senna's explanation isn't satisfactory, why not? How are you defining open sets?

Comment: Senna is right, I did not say so.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @ajotatxe it was not mine

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Of course, you can't vote (up or down) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is empty, then it is open. If not, let be $z\in A$. Let $\epsilon=\frac12\min\{r-|z-z_0|,s-|z-z_1|\}$. Now choose $w$ such that $|w-z|<\epsilon$. Apply triangular inequality to prove that $w\in A$.

For example: $|w-z_0|\le |w-z|+|z-z_0|<\epsilon+|z-z_0|<r-|z-z_0|+|z-z_0|=r$

Answer (score 0):

No. What you did doesn't prove that $A$ is open. In order to prove that $A$ is open, choose an arbitrary $z$ in $A$ and show that there exists some neighbourhood of $z$ lying entirely within $A$.

What you did is to choose an $\epsilon$ and show that for all $z$ in $A$, $|z-z_0| < \epsilon$ and $|z-z_1| < \epsilon$. This doesn't in anyway prove that $A$ is open!